# Connection SSL - Chromecast

Tags: c, ssl, chromecast

I make a simple app for send request to chromecast.
But, my app doens't recv any data.

Here my program :

[main.c](https://code.empreintesduweb.com/11582.html)

[ssl.c](https://code.empreintesduweb.com/11583.html)

Comment: Don't link code, questions should be self-contained. Also read about [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that `offset += pack_I( buffer , 0 , offset );` is correct? Try to write the query before sending it.

Comment: Yes, i think...
I need put 3 part (len buffer / len buffer and buffer)

Comment: Can you provide the error logs?